# AsyncTask add to class ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to write an AsyncTask that will use the Google Places API to get nearby locations. The actual functionality is working correctly, however, when my task finishes the class variables `locationNames` and `locationIDs` aren't written to. I've tried the behavior in my code as both progress updates and as a post execute and neither work. How do I add Strings to my ArrayLists in MainActivity from the AsyncTask?

```
package billy.cs436.googleplaces;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    String searchURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?";
    private HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    Location mLocation;
    ArrayList<String> locationNames;
    ArrayList<String> locationIDs;
    ArrayList<String> locationAddresses;
    ArrayList<String> locInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        double latitude, longitude;

        locationNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        locationIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
        locationAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
        locInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

        // location
        mLocation = new Location("");
        // sample coordinates
        latitude = 38.989697;
        longitude = -76.937760;
        mLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        mLocation.setLongitude(longitude);

        // ASSEMBLE URL
        searchURL += "location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&";
        // radius
        searchURL += "radius=100&";
        // api key
        searchURL += "key=" + getString(R.string.api_key);

        // Fill locationNames and locationIDs
        new findLocationsNearMe().execute(mLocation);

        // NOW USE PLACE IDS TO REQUEST SPECIFIC INFO TO GET FULL ADDRESS
        // new getAddresses().execute(locationIDs);

        printInfo();

    }

    public class findLocationsNearMe extends AsyncTask<Location,String[],Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Location... locations) {
            JSONObject json = getJSON();
            try {
                JSONArray locationParser = json.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 1; i < locationParser.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject locationInfo = locationParser.getJSONObject(i);
                    String[] loc = new String[2];
                    loc[0] = String.valueOf(locationInfo.get("name"));
                    loc[1] = String.valueOf(locationInfo.get("place_id"));

                    publishProgress(loc);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String[]... value) {
            String name = String.valueOf(value[0][0]);
            String id = String.valueOf(value[0][1]);
            Log.d("PROGRESS UPDATE: ", name + "  " + id);
            locationNames.add(name);
            locationIDs.add(id);
        }


        protected JSONObject getJSON() {
            String JSONresult;
            try {
                // make request
                URL url = new URL(searchURL);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                if (builder.length() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                // return json object
                reader.close();
                JSONresult = builder.toString();
                return new JSONObject(JSONresult);


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("JSON PROBLEM", "return new object failed!");
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println("LocationNames: " + locationNames);
        System.out.println("LocationIDs: " + locationIDs);;
    }
}
```

The log shows the correct values for Names and IDs from the ProgressUpdate, but printInfo prints `LocationNames: []` and `LocationIDs: []`

EDIT 1:

Per the suggestion in the comments from @GhostCat, I implemented a `NearbyLocation` class and I also finished up my method to get addresses. Here is the full code. (I'm not sure if the correct procedure here is to replace my old code or post in this EDIT 1 format. If I should just delete the older code above to shorten this post let me know.)

```
package billy.cs436.googleplaces;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    String searchURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?";
    private HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    Location mLocation;
    ArrayList<NearbyLocation> nearbyLocations;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        double latitude, longitude;

        nearbyLocations = new ArrayList<>();

        mLocation = new Location("");
        // sample coordinates
        latitude = 38.989697;
        longitude = -76.937760;
        mLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        mLocation.setLongitude(longitude);

        // ASSEMBLE URL
        searchURL += "location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&";
        // radius
        searchURL += "radius=100&";
        // api key
        searchURL += "key=" + getString(R.string.api_key);

        // Fill locationNames and locationIDs
        new findLocationsNearMe().execute(mLocation);

         //NOW USE PLACE IDS TO REQUEST SPECIFIC INFO TO GET FULL ADDRESS
         new getAddresses().execute();

        printInfo();

    }

    public class findLocationsNearMe extends AsyncTask<Location,NearbyLocation,Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Location... locations) {
            JSONObject json = getJSON();
            try {
                JSONArray locationParser = json.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 1; i < locationParser.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject locationInfo = locationParser.getJSONObject(i);
                    NearbyLocation loc = new NearbyLocation(String.valueOf(locationInfo.get("name")),
                            String.valueOf(locationInfo.get("place_id")), null);

                    publishProgress(loc);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(NearbyLocation... value) {
            String name = value[0].getName();
            String id = value[0].getId();
            Log.d("PROGRESS UPDATE: ", name + "  " + id);
            nearbyLocations.add(value[0]);
        }

        protected JSONObject getJSON() {
            String JSONresult;
            try {
                // make request
                URL url = new URL(searchURL);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                if (builder.length() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                // return json object
                reader.close();
                JSONresult = builder.toString();
                return new JSONObject(JSONresult);


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("JSON PROBLEM", "return new object failed!");
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class getAddresses extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String detail = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            for(NearbyLocation loc : nearbyLocations) {
                String detailURL = detail + "placeid=" + loc.getId() + "&key=" + getString(R.string.api_key);
                JSONObject json = getJSON(detailURL);
                JSONObject locationParser = null;
                try {
                    locationParser = json.getJSONObject("result");
                    loc.setAddress(locationParser.get("formatted_address").toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        public JSONObject getJSON(String detailURL) {
            String JSONresult;
            try {
                // make request
                URL url = new URL(detailURL);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                if (builder.length() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                // return json object
                reader.close();
                JSONresult = builder.toString();
                return new JSONObject(JSONresult);


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("JSON PROBLEM", "return new object failed!");
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println("size...  " + nearbyLocations.size());
        for(NearbyLocation loc : nearbyLocations) {
            System.out.println("LOCATION: " + loc.getName() + "  " + loc.getAddress());
        }
    }

    public class NearbyLocation {
        String name;
        String address;
        String id;
        public NearbyLocation(String name, String id, String address) {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setName(String n) {
            name = n;
        }

        public void setAddress(String a) {
            address = a;
        }

        public void setId(String i) {
            id = i;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: your abstractions are wrong. Create a single class that represents a Location (with name, id, address, info); and store objects of that class within **one** list; instead of using **four** lists to store the 4 parts that make up a location! (of course, this is not really related to your question, but it will make your code a lot simpler; and simple code is easier to debug than complex code)

Comment: Good point. I'll make that change and will post if it magically fixes my issue :)